# $f :\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous differentiable with $|f′(x)| \leq (x^2 + 1)^{−1}$ for all x ∈ R. Show that $\lim $ x→+∞ $f(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

If $f :\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous differentiable with $|f′(x)| \leq (x^2 + 1)^{−1}$ for all $x \in\mathbb R.$ Show that $\lim_{ x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

Hi guys,
So I've been trying to solve this problem.  I thought that I could use that  $\lim_{x\to\infty} |f’(x)|=0$ to then show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, which I thought made intuitively kinda sense until I discovered some counter examples.
Now, because I’m stuck I really would appreciate if someone could give me a hint and/or point me to a concept which could help to solve the exercise.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: If the limit does not exist, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N$, there are $x>y>N$ with $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$. Use the FTOC to derive a contradiction.

Comment: $f(x)=\ln x$ has $|f’(x)|\to 0,$ so that is not good enough to prove $f$ has a limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proving the existence of a limit without knowledge of the actual value of the limit usually involves the *completeness* of the underlying space, i.e. using that Cauchy sequences are convergent. Here one can proceed as follows:

- First note that for $0 < R < a < b$
  $$
   |f(b) - f(a)| \le \int_a^b |f'(t) \, dt \le \int_a^b \frac{dt}{1+t^2} \\
  = \arctan(b)-\arctan(a) \le \frac \pi 2 - \arctan(R) 
  $$
  and the right-hand side becomes arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $R$.
- Conclude that $(f(n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, so that $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ exists.
- Finally conclude that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = L$.